# How to select dropdown by inserting value in the text box

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hello i have a dropdown which is fetching data from a database. Forget about the database, i have a text box in front of the dropdown select. The logic is if i type in the text the value should be selected automatically from the dropdown if the value typed in the text not matched with the values in the dropdown, then the user can select the dropdown. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my html code!

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Scheme**</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" name="scheme" id="scheme">
                        <?php
                        for ($column = 'A'; $column <= $lastcol; $column++) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $column . '">' . $worksheet->getCell($column . '1')->getValue() . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_scheme" name="txt_scheme" placeholder="Or Type here">
                </div>
            </div>
```

In dropdown i m getting these values

```
QC code 
Analyte 
Assay Value 
Assigned Value  
STANDARDDEVIATION   
ACCEPTABLEMIN   
ACCEPTABLEMAX   
Sample ID   
Date
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Any code?

Comment: @xale94 actually i dont know where to begin with but only i have a html fields about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label for="">Enter Value</label>
<input type="text" class="textVal">
<select name="" id="listItems">
</select>


var listItems = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six"];

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  console.log(listItems[i]);
  $("#listItems").append("<option>" + listItems[i] + "</option>")
}

$(".textVal").on("focusout",function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    console.log(listItems[i]);
    if(listItems[i] == $(this).val()) {
        $("#listItems").val($(this).val());
    }    
  }
})
```

Comment: this is not working it should select the dropdown value automatically from the text box

Comment: May i know what exactly you want to be done..As per your question what i understood is that value of dropdown should be set from input.

Rephrase your question here @adeel

Comment: No @krishna9960  actually i was selecting the value from dropdown now i want that there should be text box also if i type in the text it should automatically select the value from the dropdown. Lets say from above code in my dropdown value, i type QC code so by typing in the text it should automatically select the QC code from the dropdown. I hope you can understand now. :)

Comment: @adeel Do you need somethig like this http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2469/

Comment: Do you want something like this Combo Box Functionality

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @VilasKumkar no its not like that lets say i type Four in the text box it should automatically select the Four from dropdown. I hope you understand now.

Comment: @Krishna9960 from the jsfiddle you have sent me just check that if i type Four it should select Four from the dropdown automatically.

Comment: @VilasKumkar
You missed to set value attribute of option.....
Updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2477/

Does he wants this ??

 Input is case sensitive so type first letter capital

Comment: @adeel

 Updated your fiddle jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2477

This should work fot u

Comment: Yeah this is good! just tell me it will automatically select the dropdown value because i want to sent it to the database.

Comment: Updated the answer above as well . So i think you are done with this issue

Comment: Yes there is an Event(Focus Out) on textbox As soon as your focus goes out of the textbox the event will get triggered and value will be set. So you can pass the value to database at the same time. Before making a request just check whether the value is present in the select box and you should be fine posting data to database

Comment: @Krishna9960 Thankx buddy much help provided.

Comment: @Krishna9960 hi! dude i tried but the problem is my value of option is different from the text of option. Like 'One' have value 'A'. So it is not working on the text box like if i type in the text 'One'. it does not match with the value of dropdown. Any help you can provide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135235/discussion-between-krishna9960-and-adeel).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, then you can modified with your need.

```
$("#product").on("change keyup paste", function(){ 
    var valuefound =''; 
    $("#platformid option").each(function(i){
      if($(this).text().substring(0, 2).toLowerCase()==$("#product").val().substring(0, 2).toLowerCase() ){ valuefound = $(this).val(); } }); 
   $('option:selected', 'select[name="platformid"]').removeAttr('selected'); $('#platformid option[value="' + valuefound + '"]').prop('selected', true); })
```

Working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8xfqeb9y/

Comment: Yeah This is the best solution but krishna solution is also too good. Thankx for this @sabari k

Answer (score 1):

check now that values and texts are different and you can even select now by typing one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
        $("#txtselect").keyup(function(){
         $("#selbox > option").each(function() {
                if($(this).text()==$("#txtselect").val())
                {
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
   });
        });
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selbox">
<option val="select">select</option>
<option val="123">one</option>
<option val="abc">two</option>
<option val="23sfd">three</option>
<option val="27345">four</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtselect"/>


</body>
</html>
```

check this you will get solution run snippet and type "one"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
        $("#txtselect").keyup(function(){
         $("#selbox").val($("#txtselect").val());
        });
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selbox">
<option val="select">select</option>
<option val="one">one</option>
<option val="two">two</option>
<option val="three">three</option>
<option val="four">four</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtselect"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried and it worked perfectly. but the problem is the value of option is different from the text which is showing. For example for the select the value is A, for the the one value is B and i cannot change the value of option. is there any solution?

Comment: @adeel please check the updated one now,values and texts were different and you can select by typing text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getselected(elem)
    {
        var textvalue = $(elem).val();
        if(textvalue != '')
        {
            $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('select option').removeAttr('selected');
            $('select option').each(function(){
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(textvalue) > -1)
                {
                    $('select').val($(this).attr('value'));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('select').val('');
            $('select').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }                
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="name" value="" onkeydown="getselected(this)">
<select disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">QC code</option>
    <option value="2">Analyte</option>
    <option value="3">Assay Value</option> 
    <option value="4">Assigned Value</option>  
    <option value="5">STANDARDDEVIATION</option>  
    <option value="6">ACCEPTABLEMIN</option>   
    <option value="7">ACCEPTABLEMAX</option>   
    <option value="8">Sample ID</option>
    <option value="9">Date</option>
</select>
```