# select and input in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any plugin or way to make select with search option, and if there is no option like entered in search that entered value would be like input..

Have form with lots of manufacturers and models to select.. but also there is lots of new ones and want to make it in one place.. so that wouldn't need to go another page ant save the model or manufacturer..

for now thinking about making it with `chosen` plugin (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) like tag input.. but still more want to make like select with input in  one..

also must work with select/input with names of array like `manufacturer_id[]` etc..

Comment: This is a small example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112387/how-to-select-dropdown-by-inserting-value-in-the-text-box/42113541#42113541

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Select2 ? 
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Maybe you can do something with it.

Comment: select2 not working with names with arrays like `select_name[0]` etc...